# Need Assistance on ASUS K55V USB ports not working

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb

I have an Asus K55V laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium x64. Whenever I try to use a mouse (or any other USB device), it doesn't work because of a driver problem.

The automatic update tries to update the driver and requires me to reboot directly after. It doesn't work. Windows Update then wants to re-attempt the update and then I have to reboot (etc). Now, after 10 tries it still doesn't work.

No USB ports work at the moment, it has 2 USB 3.0 ports and 1 USB 2.0 port. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: From @leaveswater02: For the USB3.0 ports try the ASUS (http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K55VD/HelpDesk_Download/), AsMedia 3.0 Driver under the USB section and for USB 2.0 try the Intel Management Engine under the Others section.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update the USB driver manually in the device manager. Assuming this is for Windows

[W7 guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/update-drivers-windows-7.htm)

[Vista guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/updatedrvvista.htm)

[XP guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/updatedriverxp.htm)

[image]

Comment: i tried to, but it did not give me permission for it as it seemed the latest driver already was installed, but it isnt working correctly

Comment: Yes, the error occurs at every USB port.

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium 64 Bit

Comment: Please download the USB driver from http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&m=K55VM&hashedid=oEV4AqhtsyxoQXaF and then use this driver instead of the default OS version.

Comment: Thanks for the support, but yet again, only the USB 3.0 has updates available, which makes USB 2.0 useless?

Comment: When you plug in a device into the USB2.0 port, does Windows detect it? This will confirm if the port is working or not

Comment: It used to detect it, but now it doesn't detect anything. so it was working, but now it doesn't

Comment: Please uninstall the driver via Device manager. Then reboot and see if Windows detects it.

Comment: Still not detected

Comment: And in device manager, scan your computer for changes - also, please ensure the USB device is enabled. If this fails, I suggest you take it back to the shop as it now sounds like a hardware failure.

Comment: It still didnt work, so yea, I shall go see an hardware specialist about it. And if there are any costs im going to ask for a refund since its not my fault.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a very common faults with ASUS laptops and the root cause of the problem at least for newer laptops is the USB fast charge or USB Boost charge software. Uninstall that and you're all set. 
Hope this helped.

Comment: WAT, seriously? I never tried that on mine! I will test it, be right back!

Comment: Sadly this didn't worked on my laptop :( (N46VM, the USB  3.0 port never worked since I purchased it years ago)

Answer (score 0):

For the USB3.0 ports try the ASUS AsMedia 3.0 Driver under the USB section and for USB 2.0 try the Intel Management Engine under the Others section.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information.  Unfortunately, link-only answers are discouraged.  Super User compiles questions and answers for reference and if the link disappears or is unavailable, the answer has no value.  Answers are expected to be self-contained and definitive, which makes it hard to answer questions like this one.  Helpful suggestions can be left as comments, which you need a little more rep for.  I moved the information to a comment so it doesn't disappear if the answer gets deleted.  You might want to delete the answer so it doesn't get downvoted, which would eat into your rep.

Comment: Your edit turned a link-only answer to a linkless link-only answer.  The information, including the link so it makes sense, is in a comment, with credit to you.  Consider deleting this answer so your rep isn't at risk from potential downvotes.

Comment: Can you place the links back? I would appreciate them, maybe they would help with my own problem...

Comment: @speeder: You can see earlier versions of posts by looking at [the revision history](http://superuser.com/posts/860696/revisions). (… teach a man to fish …)